# OpenGL vertices color

Tags: opengl, colors, vertex, vertex-shader

I am trying to build an editor with OpenGL where I will draw lines, polygons, triangles...The problem is that I want to pass ONE color for all vertices. I know how to send a color for each vertex, but I want to send only one color for all vertices. Can anyone help? I think I should do it with vertex shader. Also I am using only Qglfunctions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a `vec4` uniform in your fragment shader to hold the color and use that to populate `gl_FragColor`.

Comment: This helps me a lot. when I decalare vec4 mycolor and use it as gl_FragColor = mycolor. How can I pass in mycolor to fragment shader?